# How to debug/solve MySQL JDBC connection timeout

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection

I am migrating a Java application with a MySQL DB. Now the connection times out at some point, although the same one with the same params worked fine a couple of transactions before. here is the code:

public class DBConnection {

```
public DBConnection() {
    super();
}

public static Connection getConnection(String database, String port,
        String schema, String username, String password)
        throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Connecting to DB:");

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"
            + database + ":" + port + "/" + schema, username, password);
            System.out.println("Connection success: " + connection.isValid(3));

    return connection;
}
```

}

And my logs:

> 2016-06-21 15:48:32,621 DEBUG
>   [xxx]
>   (default task-21) Statement: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
>   'C:/CostCenter_Data/common/date_dim.csv' INTO TABLE
>   il_costcenter.tbl_dim_date fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"'
>   lines terminated by ' 2016-06-21 15:48:32,621 DEBUG
>   [xxx]
>   (default task-21) ' IGNORE 1 LINES 2016-06-21 15:48:33,011 DEBUG
>   [xxx]
>   (default task-21) Connecting to DB: 2016-06-21 15:48:33,011 DEBUG
>   [xxx]
>   2016-06-21 15:48:33,027 DEBUG
>   [xxx]
>   (default task-21) Connection success: true 2016-06-21 15:48:33,027
>   DEBUG
>   [xxx]
>   (default task-21) Executing statement... 2016-06-21 15:48:33,027 DEBUG
>   [xxx]
>   (default task-21) truncate table costcenter.tbl_dim_date 2016-06-21
>   15:48:33,246 DEBUG
>   [xxx]
>   (default task-21) Connecting to DB: 2016-06-21 15:48:33,246 DEBUG
>   [xxx]
>   (default task-21) Connection success: true 2016-06-21 15:48:33,246
>   DEBUG
>   [xxx]
>   (default task-21) Executing statement... 2016-06-21 15:48:33,246 DEBUG
>   [xxx]
>   (default task-21) insert into costcenter.tbl_dim_date (date_qualifier
>   ,week_id ,month_id ,quarter_id ,year_id ,previous_date
>   ,last_month_date ,last_quarter_date ,last_year_date ,date_begin_ts
>   ,date_end_ts ,day_of_week_id ,weekday_flag ,last_day_in_month
>   ,week_begin_date ,week_end_date ) select date_qualifier ,week_id
>   ,month_id ,quarter_id ,year_id ,previous_date ,last_month_date
>   ,last_quarter_date ,last_year_date ,date_begin_ts ,date_end_ts
>   ,day_of_week_id ,case weekday_flag when 'true' then true else false
>   end as weekday_flag ,case last_day_in_month when 'true' then true else
>   false end as last_day_in_month ,week_begin_date ,week_end_date from
>   il_costcenter.tbl_dim_date  2016-06-21 15:48:33,699 DEBUG
>   [xxx]
>   (default task-21) Connecting to DB: 2016-06-21 15:48:33,699 DEBUG 
>   2016-06-21 15:53:31,404 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction
>   Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check timeout for TX
>   0:ffff0a00016d:-382678fc:5769432f:39 in state  RUN 2016-06-21
>   15:53:31,404 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker
>   0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id
>   0:ffff0a00016d:-382678fc:5769432f:39 invoked while multiple threads
>   active within it. 2016-06-21 15:53:31,404 WARN 
>   [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012381:
>   Action id 0:ffff0a00016d:-382678fc:5769432f:39 completed with multiple
>   threads - thread default task-21 was in progress with
>   java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
>   java.io.FileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
>   java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
>   java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
>   java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
>   java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
>   xxx
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
>   org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
>   org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SFSBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SFSBInvocationInterceptor.java:57)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor.processInvocation(StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor.java:125)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
>   org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
>   org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulComponentInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(StatefulComponentInstanceInterceptor.java:65)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:254)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:329)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
>   org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
>   org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
>   org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
>   xxxPersistenceService$$$view3.invokeTEL(Unknown
>   Source) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:436)
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
>   xxx.PersistenceService$Proxy$_$$*Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.invokeTEL(Unknown
>   Source)
>   xxx.PersistenceService$Proxy$*$$*WeldClientProxy.invokeTEL(Unknown
>   Source)
>   xxx.FileManagementService.archiveFile(FileManagementService.java:83)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
>   org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
>   org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
>   org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
>   org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
>   org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
>   org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
>   org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
>   org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
>   org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>   org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
>   xxx.FileManagementService$$$view6.archiveFile(Unknown
>   Source) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:436)
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:67)
>   org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
>   xxx.FileManagementService$Proxy$*$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.archiveFile(Unknown
>   Source)
>   xxx.FileManagementController.archiveFile(FileManagementController.java:154)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:308)
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:415)
>   javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:285)
>   com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
>   org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>   org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>   javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
>   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>   org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener.processAction(DialogActionListener.java:45)
>   javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
>   javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
>   org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> 2016-06-21 15:53:31,436 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction
>   Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012108: CheckedAction::check - atomic action
>   0:ffff0a00016d:-382678fc:5769432f:39 aborting with 1 threads active!
>   2016-06-21 15:53:31,436 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (Transaction Reaper
>   Worker 0) WFLYTX0027: The pre-jca synchronization
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor$StatefulSessionSynchronization@e921ad
>   associated with tx TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction:
>   0:ffff0a00016d:-382678fc:5769432f:39 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >
>   failed during after completion: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.OwnableReentrantLock.unlock(OwnableReentrantLock.java:120)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor.releaseLock(StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor.java:181)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor.releaseInstance(StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor.java:173)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor$StatefulSessionSynchronization.afterCompletion(StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor.java:250)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.txn.service.internal.tsr.JCAOrderedLastSynchronizationList.afterCompletion(JCAOrderedLastSynchronizationList.java:147)
>     at
>   com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.afterCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:96)
>     at
>   com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.afterCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:545)
>     at
>   com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.afterCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:476)
>     at
>   com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.cancel(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:130)
>     at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.cancel(AtomicAction.java:215)
>     at
>   com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TransactionReaper.doCancellations(TransactionReaper.java:381)
>     at
>   com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.coordinator.ReaperWorkerThread.run(ReaperWorkerThread.java:78)
>
> 2016-06-21 15:53:31,436 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction
>   Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012121: TransactionReaper::doCancellations
>   worker Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] successfully
>   canceled TX 0:ffff0a00016d:-382678fc:5769432f:39

The JDBC version matches DB-MySQL version, I don't know where to look or what error sources to consider anymore.
Oh and the timeout is set to 5 mins, so that's not it.

Big Thanks for any help!

P.S. Application and Db are both running on the same secured windows server, I access via localhost:3306, external access is blocked

Comment: Gut-Feeling: You have a connection leak somewhere and at some point no new clients to MySQL can be created. How do you make sure you close all connections after use? Maybe consider using a connection pool

Comment: You say the same one. You mean the same CSV file? If not, what are the sizes of the files for success versus error?

Comment: Oddly, the time difference from top to bottom is exactly 5 minutes. The same 5 minute value you reference.

Comment: What you ought to do is have your own small log file that you write to in append mode. Before you start the call, write out a begin. At the end, write out an end. Obvious include on the line a timestamp (human readable preferred, not a unixtimestamp, unless that is your thing). If you find something nasty happening, then address it. For `LOAD DATA INFILE` include the file name in the output with that timestamp. If the file is too large, break it up or tweak your timeout values.

Comment: No, the same Connection (or at least the same parameters). The connection limit is set to default of 151, so that can't be it (although a pool would be better, indeed). The LOAD data INFILE statement works, it's the insert that times out. On the old machine that didn't even took a second, and if I run it locally in MySQL workbench it's through in that time, too. So the transaction does timeout after the specified 5 minutes, but not because of a large statement or performance issues regarding the statement

Answer (score 1):

check in mysql when this issue happen how many connections are established - you may use:

```
mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

it will provide you information about number of opened connections to your MySQL DB.

Maybe try to use setAutocommit(true) or if there is a lot of data (performance issue) use batch mode and insert data in series and commit after each.

Comment: Looked at that already, but not the case, since the application is the only one accessing the DB. Good hint though :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.
I think it was this piece of code within java.sql.DriverManager, but I can't verify that. My guess is that the synchronized was blocking something, since a connection leak was not the problem (The returned Connection in the original code is used in a try block, which since java 7 or 8 closes everything that implements Autocloseable interface automatically)

```
private static Connection getConnection(
        String url, java.util.Properties info, Class<?> caller) throws SQLException {
        /*
         * When callerCl is null, we should check the application's
         * (which is invoking this class indirectly)
         * classloader, so that the JDBC driver class outside rt.jar
         * can be loaded from here.
         */
        ClassLoader callerCL = caller != null ? caller.getClassLoader() : null;
        synchronized(DriverManager.class) {
            // synchronize loading of the correct classloader.
            if (callerCL == null) {
                callerCL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            }
        }
```

What I did was using a connection pool:

http://www.javatips.net/blog/dbcp-connection-pooling-example